# Can't transfer Matic to smart contract

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, erc20, ethers.js

I'm trying to transfer Matic to my smart contract in the Mumbai test net using ethers.

I'm using the most basic contract which comes with hardhat - Greeter. sol.

The error I keep getting is(in the polygonscan-mumbai):
[image]

The client side transfer using ethers:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
const signer = provider.getSigner();
const erc20Contract = new ethers.Contract("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001010", erc20abi, signer);
const parsedAmount = ethers.utils.parseUnits(amount.toString(), 'ether');
const transferTokens = await erc20Contract.transfer(contractAddress , parsedAmount);
```

Greeter.sol:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract Greeter {
    string private greeting;

    constructor(string memory _greeting) {
        console.log("Deploying a Greeter with greeting:", _greeting);
        greeting = _greeting;
    }

    function greet() public view returns (string memory) {
        return greeting;
    }

    function setGreeting(string memory _greeting) public {
        console.log("Changing greeting from '%s' to '%s'", greeting, _greeting);
        greeting = _greeting;
    }
}
```

Also when I manually try to send Matic to the smart contract using metamsk it's giving me the same error(only to contracts, not other wallets).
But if I try other tokens it works fine - am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your contract needs to implement either `receive()` or `fallback()` function to be able to accept native currency of the network.

Docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/contracts.html#special-functions

Example:

```
contract Greeter {
    // ...

    receive() external payable {
    }
}
```

Comment: After implementing receive() I can transfer Matic to the smart contract using Metamask. But when I try to erc20Contract.transfer() it's still giving me the same error in the polygon scan. For some unknown reason, it's trying to transfer the Matic to the Matic contract(?). Disclaimer - contractAddress is the correct address of the smart contract.

Comment: @AlonBenYaakov Transferring ERC20 tokens is different thing from transferring native tokens. Note that MATIC is an ERC20 token on Ethereum but native token on Polygon... Can you post a separate question with steps to reproduce the other issue that you mentioned in the comment?